# SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2014 ; Error 40

Tags: sql-server-2014

I just installed MS SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2014 , but when I open it I have to add a server name to connect  it but it is showing me following error when I enter server name.

**TITLE: Connect to Server**

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2) The system cannot find the file specified**

I don't know what to do now, help me out please.
Thanks
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btQrs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine, if it helps. See if you should have more to it, like SQLEXPRESSPC in my case.

[image: My Screenshot]

Comment: rudy i tried it but still facing the same error i have reinstalled it 3 to 4 times but nothing working.

Comment: Then the next obvious question would be whether you even have SQL Server installed. Management Studio is only the interface for DB administration, not a DB per se.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an `instance name`.

Instance Name has been provided during the installation process of SQL Server.

Inside the `Server name` combobox, you should type something like : `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\MSSQLEXPRESS` depending on your version of SQLServer.

The `.\` refer to your local machine.